# how to delete a word in R from a string using regex

Tags: r, regex

Hi I would like to delete blanks (check no.170) and many others from the below. any idea how can i go about it?

```
words2                        
 [116] "been"             "any"              "reasonable"       "cause"            "for"             
 [121] "such"             "apprehension"     "Indeed"           "the"              "most"            
 [126] "ample"            "evidence"         "to"               "the"              "contrary"        
 [131] "has"              "all"              "the"              "while"            "existed"         
 [136] "and"              "been"             "open"             "to"               "their"           
 [141] "inspection"       "It"               "is"               "found"            "in"              
 [146] "nearly"           "all"              "the"              "published"        "speeches"        
 [151] "of"               "him"              "who"              "now"              "addresses"       
 [156] "you"              "I"                "do"               "but"              "quote"           
 [161] "from"             "one"              "of"               "those"            "speeches"        
 [166] "when"             "I"                "declare"          "that"             ""                
 [171] "I"                "have"             "no"               "purpose"          "directly"        
 [176] "or"               "indirectly"       "to"               "interfere"        "with"            
 [181] "the"              "institution"      "of"               "slavery"          "in"              
 [186] "the"              "States"           "where"            "it"               "exists"          
 [191] "I"                "believe"          "I"                "have"             "no"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you had a vector `x = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1)` and you wanted to remove all `2`s, you might do this: `x[x != 2]`. Similarly, you have a vector `words2` and you want to remove the blanks `""`, so you can do this: `words2[words2 != ""]`.

Of course, to remove them from `words2` and save the result, you need to use `<-` or `=` to overwrite `words2`, as in

```
words2 = words2[words2 != ""] ## remove blanks

words2 = words2[nchar(words2) > 0] ## keep only strings with more than 0 characters

## remove blank and "bad string" strings
words2 = word2[! words2 %in% c("", "bad string")]
```

Regex is useful if you are looking inside strings (e.g., remove strings that contain an "a"), or if you are using patterns (e.g., remove strings that have a number at the end). When you are looking for exact matches of a whole string, you don't need regex.